# Curvature on product Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am working on the following problem from Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds*: Suppose $g = g_1 \oplus g_2$ is a product metric on $M_1 \times M_2$   (i.e. $$g(X_1+X_2,Y_1+Y_2) = g_1(X_1,Y_1)+g_2(X_2,Y_2),$$ where $$X = X_1 + X_2, Y = Y_1+Y_2 \in T_{(p_1,p_2)}(M_1 \times M_2) = T_{p_1}M_1 \oplus T_{p_2}M_2.$$

(a) Show that for each point $p_i \in M_i$, the submanifolds $M_1 \times \{ p_2 \}$ and $\{ p_1 \} \times M_2$ are totally geodesic.

(b) If II $\subseteq T(M_1 \times M_2)$ is a 2-plane spanned by $X_1 \in TM_1$ and $X_2 \in TM_2$, show that $K$(II) $= 0$ (the sectional curvature is $0$).

(c) Show that the product metric on $S^2 \times S^2$ has nonnegative sectional curvature.

(d) Show that there is an embedding of $T^2$ in $S^2 \times S^2$ such that the induced metric is flat.

For part (a), I think I should be showing that the second fundamental form vanishes identically, but I'm not having any luck actually proving that.  I tried using the Weingarten equation, but got nowhere.  For part (b), I think that, using the formula for sectional curvature, this reduces to showing that $Rm(X_1,X_2,X_2,X_1) = 0$, but again I'm not having any luck proving that.  For (c), I think that if we take an arbitrary plane and use an orthonormal basis, we might be able to get something, but to be honest I'm just totally lost.  I have no idea for part (d).  Any help is MUCH appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that Riemannian distance is infimum of length of curves (Here
length is calculated by using Riemannian metric) Hence product has a
product metric $g:=g_1+ g_2$ so that we have formula $$
d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2 + d_2(x_2,y_2)^2} $$

(a) Note that distance between two points $(x_i,p_2)$ in $M_1\times
\{p_2\}$ is equal to distance between $x_i$. Hence we concluded that
a geodesic curve in $M_1$ is in fact a geodesic curve in $M_1\times
p_2$ Hence $M_1$ is a totally geodesic

(b) $E_i,\ E_\alpha$ are coordinate vector fields in $M_i$
respectively $$ \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^j = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk} (g_{k
\alpha,\beta } +g_{k\beta,\alpha}-g_{\alpha\beta,k} ) =0
$$

By calculating others, ${\rm sec}\
(E_i,E_\alpha)=0$

(c) If $M_i=S^2$, then $$ {\rm sec}\ (E_i,E_j)={\rm sec}\ (S^2),\
{\rm sec}\ (E_i,E_\alpha ) =0 $$

(d) $T^2=S^1\times S^1\subset S^2\times S^2$ Here $S^1$ is a
geodesic curve in $S^2$. Then $T^2$ is totally geodesic so that $
{\rm sec}\ (T^2)=0$